# Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

I want to get a table to show the percentage of population in different countries.

For example,

| Percentage | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | USA |
| 25 | UK |

I write and run codes below in https://dbpedia.org/sparql. When I run the code, I get a list of decimals in the attached picture.

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT (xsd:double(?population) / SUM(xsd:double(?population)) * 100)
WHERE {
?country dbo:populationTotal ?population .
}
GROUP BY ?population
```

Close to what I want to achieve but the respective countries' names are not shown. So I write a new code.

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT (xsd:double(?population) / SUM(xsd:double(?population)) * 100)  ?country
WHERE {
?country dbo:populationTotal ?population .
}
GROUP BY ?population
GROUP BY ?country
```

[image: Percentages with no country attributes]

Then I got this error from the SPARQL Endpoint.

> Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Variable ?country is used in the result set outside aggregate and not mentioned in GROUP BY clause

Where did I do wrong? Please help me to point it out. I am eagerly to know my mistakes as this is my first time writing SPARQL queries (excitedd!)

***P.s. Yes! I have been google-searching and stack-over searching when I got this error message. But I couldn't find one.***

Comment: your first query isn't even doing what you want ... I mean, look at the result. Some values are 100%. It doesn't make sense to group by population, what you want can't simply be done a single grouping query. Nor did you look only for countries.

Comment: a draft would be `PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?country ((xsd:double(?population)/?total * 100) as ?popPercentage) {
?country dbo:populationTotal ?population ; a dbo:Country
{
SELECT (SUM(xsd:double(?pop)) as ?total) 
WHERE {
?c dbo:populationTotal ?pop ; a dbo:Country
}
}
}
order by desc(?popPercentage)

` - but as you can see, even here `dbo:Country` is useless in DBpedia and not enough. So you have to find another class or category to get only the "real" countries

Comment: once you solved this issue, another one will be the data quality in DBpedia. Have a look at the query result and you'll see the country Georgia even before China - weird, right? So, let's have a look at the DBpedia resource: https://dbpedia.org/page/Georgia_(country) - it has a total population value of `37,168,584,012,104` - no words ...

Comment: wondering where this huge number comes from? Well, DBpedia is extracted from Wikipedia infoboxes, so let's have a quick look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_(country) - you can see two numbers for 2020 estimate: `3,716,858` and `4,012,104` - concat both strings and you have the DBpedia value. Thus, the extractor/parser does fail here.

Comment: @UninformedUser wow! this is interesting to know the fact that some data in DBpedia do not make sense. I have been seeing maintenance message from DBpedia recently. I hope they are starting to fix the data quality issues now. While waiting for the fix, what are some tips and tricks we can do to increase data quality?

Comment: also one question. Is the WHERE statement optionally?

Comment: yes, the `WHERE` keyword is optional according to the SPARQL specs. I see I mixed up both versions in my query though, sorry for confusion. I think for less experienced users it might be ok to always write `WHERE` to make it more clear.

Comment: Regarding the data quality, I don't think we can do much here. The data is a dump, so it won't be changed in a while I guess until the next dump will be generated and loaded. What you can do is to open a Github issue here: https://github.com/dbpedia/extraction-framework/issues - but currently, I don't see how you could workaround this. I mean, you would have to know the errors in advance which makes the whole querying obsolete if you have the correct values.

Comment: In the meantime, once the issues are fixed, you could try [Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/) for your specific query:  `SELECT DISTINCT ?countryLabel ?population (?population/xsd:double(?total) * 100 as ?ratio) {
{SELECT (sum(?population) as ?total) { ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 ; wdt:P1082 ?population . }}
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 ;
           wdt:P1082 ?population .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?population)`

Comment: Thanks for your time. Yeap, I tested the query in Wikidata. It makes much sense as China has the highest population, and it's in the first row. About the DBpedia Github resource, I think it is helpful as well. Thanks for the sharing. For now I am going to practice more on SPARQL